# Recover/Reset OSX administrator password

Tags: macos, passwords, filevault

I'm looking for some information about how to recover my administrator password if I happen to forget it. Let's say I've had an accident and I turn on my Mac afterward and it instantly prompts me for the admin password which I do not remember. Let’s say I am not connected to the internet so I can't use my AppleID. Any solutions?

I've read something about using the recovery mode and typing in resetpassword inside the terminal window and it prompts you for a new one. Wouldn't it be too easy? This way I can easily bypass any administrator password by simply resetting it.

That's the easy question. The fact is that I have FileVault 2 enabled. Is it possible to recover the password with encryption on?

Comment: "Wouldn't it be too easy?  This way I can easily bypass any administrator password only by resetting it."  Yes, that's correct...but it can only be done via physical access.  Physical access is total access, as the saying goes.  As for FileVault, I'm pretty sure you can't recover that (without going into some very advanced memory manipulation and such)

Comment: So what you tell me is that if I had no FileVault and I had my computer stolen, I was doomed because a simple administrator password worths nothing?

Comment: Pretty much, yea.  there's recovery mode, and there's single user mode.  AS I recall, SU mode just logs you into a godmode console without any password required.  If you have FV, then you DO need the FV password, but even that can be bypassed with some new techniques (very advanced stuff that your average thief will have no idea how to do)

Comment: Oh, and as a bonus nugget of information, did you know that your wifi passwords aren't stored on the hard drive?  I put in a fresh hard drive and booted into recovery mode.  Recovery mode automatically connected to my wifi network and started downloading things for me.